# aws get tags, restrict only the info i need out of the python dic

Tags: python, boto3

using boto3 python and resourcegroupstaggingapi, how do i restrict my output to only get:

```
'Tags': [{'Key': 'Dev', 'Value': 'test_env'}, {'Key': 'Name', 'Value': 'test-tags'}]}])
```

currently it looks like this:

```
('PaginationToken', '')
('ResourceTagMappingList', [{'ResourceARN': 'arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:instance/i-057804cd7a8801114', 'Tags': [{'Key': 'Dev', 'Value': 'test_env'}, {'Key': 'Name', 'Value': 'test-tags'}]}])
('ResponseMetadata', {'RequestId': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1', 'content-length': '218', 'date': 'Mon, 30 May 2022 00:34:52 GMT'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0})
```

how can i do this ?

this is my code:

```
session = boto3.Session('get_resources')
client = boto3.client('resourcegroupstaggingapi','us-east-1')
paginator=client.get_paginator('get_resources')
        
page_iterator = paginator.paginate()

for page in page_iterator:
    for key, value in page.items():
         print(key, value)
```

Comment: you'll get more love with a properly formatted question with code snippets.  not one is going to help you with this.

Comment: thanks jonathan, i have updated the questions and added my code snippet. Is anyone able to help ?

Comment: So what's wrong with `page['ResourceTagMappingList'][0]['Tags']`?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the paginator response using a [JMESPath query](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/paginators.html#filtering-results-with-jmespath)

so something like:

```py
session = boto3.Session('get_resources')
client = boto3.client('resourcegroupstaggingapi','us-east-1')
paginator=client.get_paginator('get_resources')
        
page_iterator = paginator.paginate()
filtered_iterator = page_iterator.search("ResourceTagMappingList[].Tags[]")

for tags in filtered_iterator:
  print(tags)
```

Answer (score -1):

thank you guys. I have used something similar and filtered out further.

```
session = boto3.Session(profile_name='dev-apps-read-only')
client = session.client('resourcegroupstaggingapi',
                        region_name='ap-southeast-1')
paginator = client.get_paginator('get_resources')
page_iterator = paginator.paginate()
for page in page_iterator:
    for resource in page['ResourceTagMappingList']:
        resource_arn = resource['ResourceARN']
        tags_list = []
        for key_value_pair in resource['Tags']:
            key_name = key_value_pair['Key']
            key_value = key_value_pair['Value']
            tags_list.append(key_name)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).